# Loop through elements that start with 'req-' in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `<ul>`-s which has attributes `id`, `data-type` and `data-value`. All `id`-s have a same prefix.

```
<ul id='req-*****' data-type='***' data-value='***'>
     some <li>-s here
</ul>
. . . 
many <ul>-s here
. . .
```

I have *Javascript* function where I want to loop through this `<ul>`-s whose ids starting with *'req'* and collect `data-type` and `data-value` attribute values like that:

```
function collect(){
    var data = [];

    $.each( uls_starting_with_req, function( key, value ) {
            data.push({data_type: 'ul_data_type', data_value: 'ul_data_value'});

    });
}
```

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: But I would use a class rather than prefixing your IDs...

Comment: good remark, but I need id-s

Comment: You should use `map()` rather than each and manually creating your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function collect(){
        var data = [];
        $('ul').each(function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id.startsWith('req') ) {
                var dataType = $(this).data('type');
                var dataValue = $(this).data('value');
                data.push({data_type: dataType, data_value: dataValue})
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a way to do it:

```
var data = [];

$("ul[id^='req-']").each(function() {
  data.push({ data_type: $(this).data('type'), data_value: $(this).data('value') });
});
```

The selector selects all the `ul`s which have ID starting with `req-` and then `each` loops on them. In each iteration, the value of the data attributes can be fetched using jQuery's `data` method, which are then pushed to the array `data`.

Working example:

```js
var data = [];

$("ul[id^='req-']").each(function() {
  data.push({
    data_type: $(this).data('type'),
    data_value: $(this).data('value')
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='req-1' data-type='1' data-value='1'>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul id='req-2' data-type='2' data-value='2'>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul id='req-3' data-type='3' data-value='3'>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

using [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
function collect(){
   var data = [];
   $('ul[id^="req-"]').each(function(){
   data.push({data_type: '+ $(this).data("type") +', data_value: '+  $(this).data("value") +'});
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery attribute selector

```js
function collect() {
  var data = [];
  var getUL = $('ul[id^="req-"]');

  $.each(getUL, function(key, value) {

    data.push({
      data_type: $(value).data('type'),
      data_value: $(value).data('value')
    });

  });
  console.log(data)
}
collect()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='req-1' data-type='x' data-value='y'></ul>
<ul id='somOtherId' data-type='x2' data-value='y2'></ul>
<ul id='req-3' data-type='x3' data-value='y3'></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified brk's answer to use map off of the jQuery object

```js
function collect() {
  var getUL = $('ul[id^="req-"]');

  var data = getUL.map(function(key, value) {
    return {
      data_type: $(value).data('type'),
      data_value: $(value).data('value')
    };
  });
  
  console.log(data.get())
}

collect()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='req-1' data-type='x' data-value='y'></ul>
<ul id='somOtherId' data-type='x2' data-value='y2'></ul>
<ul id='req-3' data-type='x3' data-value='y3'></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is relevant if you have to deal with browsers different implementations/incompatibilities or if what you would like to achieve is quite verbose using vanilla JavaScript.

But if you target recent browsers, you should consider vanilla JavaScript instead since the required code in this case looks pretty the same.

```js
function collect() {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul[id^="req-"]'))
   .map(function(x) {
       return {data_type: '+ '+x.dataset.type+' +', data_value: '+ '+x.dataset.value+' +'}
   });
}

// ES6 version
function collectES6() {
   return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul[id^="req-"]'), x => {
       return {data_type: `+ ${x.dataset.type} +`, data_value: `+ ${x.dataset.value} +`}
   });
}

console.log('Vanilla version (JavaScript 1.6):', collect());
console.log('Es6 version', collectES6());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="req-x" data-type="XX" data-value="xxvalue"></ul>
<ul id="req-y" data-type="YY" data-value="ffvalue"></ul>
<ul id="req-z" data-type="ZZ" data-value="zzvalue"></ul>
```